# ggplot add extra x axis on string categorical x

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

[image]

I use ggplot to draw the above graph. Related code is here:

```
p <- ggplot(avg.dice, aes(x=type, y=average)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(aes(x=type, y=cc.average), col="red") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci.lower, ymax=ci.upper))
```

My avg.dice data frame looks like this:

```
      type   average ci.lower  ci.upper cc.average
1      e70 0.6105000    0.525 0.6850000      0.520
2      e89 0.5328000    0.480 0.6100000      0.510
3      f10 0.5902000    0.500 0.6900000      0.490
4      f15 0.4122000    0.365 0.4750000      0.335
5      f20 0.5583000    0.485 0.6200000      0.555
6      f22 0.4332000    0.365 0.4950000      0.325
7      f48 0.3113333    0.200 0.4666667      0.155
8      f80 0.5882000    0.510 0.6900000      0.355
9     i3i8 0.5438000    0.495 0.5900000      0.370
10      m5 0.5986000    0.550 0.6550000      0.485
11 series6 0.5271000    0.470 0.6000000      0.350
12 series7 0.5180000    0.450 0.5850000      0.390
13      x3 0.6190000    0.565 0.6850000      0.645
14   z4e85 0.5340000    0.485 0.6100000      0.505
```

So my x axis automatically show the type name in string. How do I add another extra x axis below the current plot that can show some numeric values related to each type? Something looks like the graph below:[image]

previously I used something like this for the extra x axis:

```
fractions = c(0.22,0.14,0.13,0.12,0.117,0.116,0.112, 0.09, 0.07,0.05,0.037,0.014,0.013,0.009)
axis(1,at=1:14,labels=fractions,line=4.5,las=2)
mtext("document\n fraction\n in CC",side=1,line=5,adj=-0.09)
```

but it won't work in ggplot, telling me that "plot.new has not been called yet"

Comment: An easy solution would be to change the names to be "value - name" so that you don't need any extra axis.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good walkaround! Is there a way to add text to a ggplot graph? Since I still need to add a description to the extra row of value in the graph.

Comment: Just add it to the x-label?